# What could keep a javascript from loading properly on a page?

Tags: javascript, windows-server-2008

We have a vendor that switched our files over to a new server.

We had a carousel on our homepage that was using javascript saved on the vendor server.

After the move the carousel javascript won't load and the carousel is broke (been working for a year and we haven't touched a file).

So the odd thing is when I debug in FF I see our css and js for the carousel - I am also using full URLs for everything so it can't be a directory issue (Windows/ASP).

Now if I take the links for css and js (they are in the same folder) and try to hit them remotely from my laptop with the carousel code saved locally, the css works but not the js.  No js in the folders they gave us work remotely.

However I see the js loaded in FF debug.  And if I copy the js, save it, and link to my local copy... the carousel works fine.  Also if I go directly to the javascript saved on vendor server... it loads fine on a page.

What could be going on?  Perm issue?

Edit:  Header info.

```
Response Headers From Cache
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Content-Length  36927
Content-Type    application/x-javascript
Date    Sun, 25 May 2014 19:55:58 GMT
Etag    "b8387cc1cc77cf1:b88"
Last-Modified   Sun, 25 May 2014 03:52:32 GMT
Server  Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
```

Comment: Have you had a look in the javascript console of your browser to see if it throws an error?

Comment: Are the JS files returning the correct `Content-Type` header?

Comment: @Steve - yes, not seeing any of the functions I need is how I deduced they weren't being loaded right.

Comment: @w3d - what am I checking?  The script types are application/javascript.  The exact files work locally.  But when copied to vendor server they don't work.  Also there are tons of script working on the page.  This one happens to be entered from an editor (crappy CMS) while the others are part of header or base html.

Comment: Well, if the _server_ is sending a `Content-Type` header of `application/javascript` (or `text/javascript`) with that JS file then it should be OK and it is something else. However, the symptoms you mention are consistent with the server sending an incorrect mime-type, or being omitted entirely (and since this problem started when you changed server that does sound quite probable). If the server does send an incorrect mime-type (such as text/plain, text/html, etc.) then the browser (particularly FF) will simply not interpret the JS file as JavaScript. How is this file served differently?

Comment: @w3d - I was just told they switched editors on their end too.  I don't really mess with the CMS a lot so I am not sure what editor they had before.  I just code our html pages and create js to run on them.  I am going to do some tests with changing the content type in the editor and see if I notice anything.  I have this carousel running on 3 websites on the internal server I manage so I know its not the script.

Comment: Yes, the fact that the same JS works OK on other websites/servers is again indicative of a `Content-Type` (ie. mime-type) issue. How did you check the "script types" mentioned above? You can check the `Content-Type` response header that the server sends in the FF debugger, under "Network".

Comment: @w3d - edited with header info.

Comment: Those headers actually look OK and that should work OK on FF. (Strictly speaking it should be `application/javascript` with no `x-`, however, that shouldn't make any difference here.) What version of FF are you using? Have you tried other browsers?

Comment: This could be an issue with Cross Origin Resource Sharing. http://enable-cors.org has more info on the subject. The point is that the server hosting resources loaded by the JavaScript file must acknowledge in HTTP headers that the resources can be used by other domains.

Comment: There are so many reasons that the JavaScript may not work that any answers to the question are just guesses.   There are lots of suggestions in the comments.   Please open a new question if you need clarification on any single one of them.